# FIR code implementation question

Tags: dsp-core

I have found this piece of code in Infenion DSP Library (asm code):

```
Fir_Blk_16()
...
;(ACC)=(ACC)+h(i)*x(n-i)<<1 as comment
```

I don't understand why the result is shifted (<<1)?

Is this for rounding purposes?

Thank you in advance,

Anton

Comment: what does the "as comment" mean here?

Comment: also, there's many reasons you might want to round – from limited accumulator bitwidth to controlling the gain of the filter intentionally. Without much more context, we could, at best, guess.

Comment: also, removed the unrelated tags. Also, is this really about a specific DSP chip? If so, please explicitily name the chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shifting is most likely related to the fixed point representation. If input, filter coefficients and accumulator are in different "Qs" (which is the fixed to float scale factor), shifts are used to adjust.

See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)